# Incrementing the existing value of a range of cells in Excel @ 1 per 100

Tags: excel, vba

I have values 1800, 102, 56, 29, 25223, 6 in cells A2, A3, A4, A5, A6 and A7 respectively. I am using VBA code to increment all the numbers by 1 per click on the Macro button "Add Number 1".

But I want to increment the above numbers by 1% per click. That means 1800 will become 1818 and not 1801; 102 will become 103.20 and not 103; 56 will become 56.56 and not 57, and so on.

A VBA code for this situation will be highly appreciated.

**Code**

```
Sub AddNumber()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngSel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Num As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lAreas As Long
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim Arr() As Variant
Set rngSel = Selection

Num = 1

For Each rng In rngSel.Areas
  If rng.Count = 1 Then
     rng = rng + Num
  Else
      lRows = rng.Rows.Count
      lCols = rng.Columns.Count
      Arr = rng
      For i = 1 To lRows
         For j = 1 To lCols
            Arr(i, j) = Arr(i, j) + Num
         Next j
      Next i
      rng.Value = Arr
  End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show your code that increments by 1.

Comment: So use `Arr(i, j) = Arr(i, j) * 1.01` instead of the `Arr(i, j) = Arr(i, j) + Num`, and `rng = rng * 1.01` instead of the `rng = rng + Num`.

Comment: You are great . Thanks a lot . My problem solved .

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
Sub AddNumber()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    .Range("A2:A7") = .[(A2:A7)*1.01]
End With

End Sub
```